# GCC stackoverflow on large array declaration

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin, mingw

Below Code works fine

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"

#define ll long long
#define endLine "\n"
using namespace std;
bool dryRun = true;

int main() {
    ll n, testCount;
    ll arr[100000];
    ll pre[100000];
    // ll pred[100000];


    cin >> testCount;
    while (testCount--) {
        cin >> n;
        cout << n;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But Adding a new array gives me stack over flow. Following code doesn't work.

```
#include "bits/stdc++.h"

#define ll long long
#define endLine "\n"
using namespace std;
bool dryRun = true;

int32_t main() {
    ll n, testCount;
    ll arr[100000];
    ll pre[100000];
    ll pred[100000];


    cin >> testCount;
    while (testCount--) {
        cin >> n;
        cout << n;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Error I get on above code:

```
Exception: STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW at rip=00100401566
rax=0000000000052228 rbx=00000000FFFFCC70 rcx=00000000FFE03C18
rdx=00000000FFFFCC70 rsi=0000000180294A00 rdi=00000000FFFFCDF0
r8 =0000000800038720 r9 =0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000040
r11=0000000000000000 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
rbp=00000000FFFFCCD0 rsp=00000000FFFFCC00
program=C:\Users\Sahitya\CLionProjects\Codeazon\cmake-build-debug\INCRDEC.exe, pid 1229, thread 
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame        Function    Args
000FFFFCCD0  00100401566 (0010040108C, 000FFFFCC70, 000FFFFCCD0, 0018004A826)
000FFFFCCD0  0000024A228 (000FFFFCC70, 000FFFFCCD0, 0018004A826, 00000000000)
000FFFFCCD0  00000000001 (000FFFFCCD0, 0018004A826, 00000000000, 00000000020)
000FFFFCCD0  0010040108C (00000000020, FF0700010302FF00, 0018004A7BA, 00180049800)
000FFFFCCD0  0018004A826 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
00000000000  00180048353 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFFFF0  00180048404 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
End of stack trace
```

I am trying to run this on a windows machine. Tried this using Cygwin and MinGW both. No Luck.
When declaring two arrays of 100000 each of type long long int, I am reserving :
**(100000 + 100000) * 8 byte => 1600000 bytes => 1600KB => 1.6MB (working).**
On declaring one more array :
**(100000 + 100000 + 100000) * 8 byte => 2400000 bytes => 2400KB => 2.4MB (not working).**

> Tried this on online IDEs, and both snippets are working fine. So probably this is an environment issue.

Comment: I stopped reading at `#define int long long` (assuming C, tags changed meanwhile)

Comment: The default stack size is _limited_. Under linux (e.g.) it is 8MB. Under windows, it is less (4MB?). So, you'll have to use `malloc` and/or `new` because the _total_ size of your arrays _exceed_ the limit.

Comment: You get stackoverflow? That's because your arrays overflow the stack. `3 * 100000 * 8 = 2400000`.

Comment: There are so many issues in this code that suggests a very bad teacher/course.

Comment: @CraigEstey Is there a way to increase this default size?

Comment: Under linux [or other POSIX compatible systems/APIs], there is `getrlimit/setrlimit` using `RLIMIT_STACK` [syscall]. I'm sure there is a native `win32` API equivalent [but I don't know what it is]. `cygwin` probably provides `getrlimit/setrlimit`. But, I'd do (e.g.): `ll *arr = new ll[100000];` or `ll *arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * 100000);` for `c`

Comment: Thanks @CraigEstey this worked for me.

Comment: You need to put those big arrays on the heap instead of the stack. Use code like `ll *arr  = calloc(100000, sizeof(ll));`, and before you exit, use `free(arr); arr = NULL;`. This will generate some type coercion warnings in C, that are easy to fix. In C++ you can use `ll * arr = new ll [100000 ];` and `delete[] arr`to be more c++ish.

Comment: Most operating systems do not allocate that much memory on the stack, you will have to use heap allocation, use `l1* arr = new l1[100000]` and `delete[] arr` before returning from main. Also use `typedef` instead of `#define` for l1.